# Invalid operands to binary expression ('const std::istream' (aka 'const basic_istream<char>') and 'std::string' [ ... ]

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do the following:

```cpp
class Book {
    std::string m_title;
    std::string m_author;
    int m_noPages;
public:
    Book(const std::istream& is) {
        std::string bookString;
        is >> bookString;

        // ...
    }
};
```

... After this, I will proceed to separate the is input into m_title, m_author, and m_noPages, but why won't the two lines above inside the constructor work?

Answer (score 3):

When reading from (and writing to) a stream, the stream is modified to track what was read (or written). This makes a `const`, thus not modifiable, stream next to useless, and it can't be used by `>>`. Remove the `const`.

```cpp
class Book {
    std::string m_title;
    std::string m_author;
    int m_noPages;
public:
    Book(const std::istream& is) {
//       ^^^^^
//       kill meeeeee! 
        std::string bookString;
        is >> bookString;

        // ...
    }
};
```

Language-wise, the prototype for `operator >>` should look something like

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, T& obj)
```

(example prototype looted from [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)).
It will accept `std::istream &`, but not a `const std::istream &`.